# Testing service session management via REST

Tags: rest, testing

I need to write test for some JAX RS web service that asserts that certain value is cached in the session from disk on the first request in the session.

The testing process does not have access to the tested process. The use case involves using REST API to invoke services.

I can think of several options to proceed with:

1. Create a REST endpoint just for testing, and query there the needed session value.
2. Write and then read a log message.

I am aware that I am trying to test an implementation detail via an external API which does not provide contract for this detail, but currently I'm a bit constrained about which processes may be run by the testing infrastructure.

Are there any additional seams to exploit for testing, and what general good practice exists for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with the idea of changing the cached resource and using the change in the behavior.